# reading file using C# on windows 10 IOT (Raspberry Pi3) exits the function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

```
private async void LeggiScoreboard(string nomeTesto)
    {
        StorageFolder folderTesto = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        StorageFile scoreboardTXT = await folderTesto.GetFileAsync("Scoreboard.txt");
        var buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(scoreboardTXT);
        using (var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))      //Leggo da un buffer e lo inserisco in una stringa
        {
            testoScoreboard = dataReader.ReadString(buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

testoScoreboard is declared as global string

the code below reads a txt file called Scoreboard.txt located in pictures library.
The txt file contains only numbers "128-255-124".
when the program tries to read the file it automatically exits the function (like an exception or something?) and obviously the string testoScoreboard is NULL.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

In Package.appxmanifest i've already put the exception on Image folder.
Sometimes it works, like once per 1000 times.

I'm using Visual studio 2015 community

EDIT:
I Decided to restart raspberry and visual studio and redoing debug... For the first time it worked well but when i rebuild and restart debugging i have got the same problem...
It looks like the txt file is already opened.

Comment: Debug, add try catch, log and see what you get.

Comment: i've the same problem using try catch. It automatically kicks me out from the function

Comment: Get the error information using `ex.Message` , for example, in `catch (Exception ex)` .  And you can launch the app from device portal without VS2015.

Comment: I don't think the file is still open. FileIO class closes the file for you are reading the file content to the buffer. Have you declared PictureLibrary capability in manifest?

Comment: By the way, try FileIO.ReadTextAsync, don't need to use a buffer and data reader, they are for reading binary data.

Comment: I tried with FileIO.ReadTextAsync too, but i've got the same problem...

Comment: Is like he doesn't find the file txt... One more thing: when i reboot the raspberry and run again the program for the first time he finds the txt file but, as soon as he reads the file, the function exits for no reason. I've declared pictureLibrary in appmanifest and try catch isn't working...